# Magento 2:- Apply custom coupon code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I created a custom module for applying custom coupon code programmatically in magento 2.
For shopping cart rule.

I have only coupon code with block and model collection check below image.

[image]

How can do it ? Any suggestion for that ?

Comment: hello.. I want to do same functionality.. coupon code is exist in custom table and I want to apply it from custom table.. is it possible? I mean u did that kind of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to inject a few classes in your constructor:

```
protected $cart;
protected $quoteRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
) {
    ...
    $this->cart= $cart;
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}
```

Then in your code you can do: **Data.php** in helper

```
public function getCouponCode(){
    $cartQuote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    return $cartQuote->getCouponCode();
}
```

Here use own create function replace `$cartQuote->getCouponCode();` to `$cartQuote->getOwnFuction();` And put code in `getOwnFuction()` for `apply custom couponCode`

And then i put in my function: **Vendor\Shipping\Model\Quote\Address\Rate.php**

```
public function importShippingRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\AbstractResult $rate)
{
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $helper = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Shipping\Helper\Data');

   $couponCode = $helper->getCouponCode();
   echo 'CouponsCode = '.$couponCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, i don't know, in which file put above code? Because this is new for me

Comment: @PayalPatel well this depends on how you developed your module. Put that code in the class that you're using to apply the coupon code programmatically

Comment: Can restrict method for particular coupon code using above code @Raphael

Comment: @PayalPatel yes you just need to replace `$couponCode` with your particular coupon code

Comment: Yaa @Raphael, you are right, but check my updated question please.

Comment: see my updated answer finally i got solution in your answer.

Comment: can anyone tell how can i apply a coupon code in a controller if i  already have the coupon code ?